# How can I define a region on the surface of a sphere in terms of the coordinates of the vertices of the boundary of the region?

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

This is a computer graphics problem. I can define the boundary of the region in terms of the vertices of a “polygon”on the surface. That is really a collection of intersecting great circles on the surface. What I would like to do is decide if a point on the surface is inside my region or not. I am struggling to come up with a function of the points or great circles that tells me if a set of coordinates is inside or not. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: You might be able to adapt ray casting to work on the surface of a sphere. I'm not an expert, though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: That’s a very interesting idea. I wonder if I can project my region on the sphere up to a tangent plane at the point and then test in 2D. Seems like it should work.

Comment: I am working on using a stereographic projection onto the tangent plane at the point in question. Then creating polygons as simplified representations of the countries. Then ray casting on the plane. I’ll post an answer if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thoughts/hints, not an answer, too long for a comment.

First, there's some ambiguity since your polygon has an inside and an outside which are distinguishable for plane polygons but not spherical ones.

The following two thoughts assume you have an order on the vertices and that you know your polygon is convex. If not, you will have to find the convex hull first (there are algorithms for that).

Perhaps you know all your points lie in the same hemisphere. Then you can assume the inside is in that hemisphere. Now stereographic projection to the plane from any point in that hemisphere converts your great circles into straight lines and standard convex polygon arguments can tell you when a point is inside.

Another possibility. For each pair of points determining an edge, find the plane through the sphere containing the great circle that joins them. Then it's easy to see which side of that plane the point you care about is on.

Comment: You are right: the fact that there are two regions “inside” is a problem. The sets of points will sometimes be in both hemispheres - we are talking about approximations of countries on the globe here. I did wonder if I could use a tangent plane at the hit point on the sphere and consider the perpendicular distances down to the vertices. I have a Miller projection map that I could use on the tangent plane. I also like your idea about considering the sides of all the great circle planes that a given point resides on. There will be a known centre point of the region to compare with.

Comment: Like a plane taking off and reaching at same point again, encircling some points of interest on the sphere.

Comment: @Tim There will be countries that lie in both the northern and southern hemispheres but probably no countries that lie in both hemispheres no matter what great circle you use for an "equator". The Miller projection won't turn great circles into straight lines: for that you want stereographic projection onto a tangent plane. Perpendicular distances will probably  be problematical. A lot depends on whether you want to do one country at a time, or many/all. So your choice of geometry really depends on your use cases. [I'd be surprised if arcgis doesn't have much of what you need.]

Answer (score 1):

In the plane, Line integral of radial rays

$\int  d\theta = 0  $  for an arbitrary external apoint $O$

and 
$ 2 \pi  $ for an internal point $I$

The rays are smooth geodesic great circle segments if we are going round a spherical surface. If the contour is a spherical polygon we have discontiuous jumps.

[image: LnInteg_IO]

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I need to do a bit of reading. The function would fit the bill if I can make it work.